# JS script not working as intended, no error message

Tags: javascript

ive got an javascript to generate random point on circle, but it just not working, and creating a straight line. pls help.
jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cLqzbLcd/.

```
$(function() {
    var h = $(document).height();
    var w = $(document).width();
    var minDimension = h < w ? h : w;
    var radius = (minDimension / 2) - 20;
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        var point = getRandomPoint(radius);
        var offset = {
            top: point.y + radius + 10,
            left: point.x + radius + 10
        };
        $("<div>").addClass("point").appendTo("body").offset(offset);
    }
});
```

Comment: @downvoter please explain the reason for the downvotes as the OP is new to SO and we should help to improve but not discourage.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Probably because the fact that OP  havent placed the whole code in OP post. And he really should, cos error was there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into your fiddle,  'math.random()' is a function, and you addres it like 'math.random'.
Change it and im sure it will work.
EDIT
[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLqzbLcd/1/)

```
function getRandomPoint(radius) {
    var angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
    return {
        x: Math.cos(angle) * radius,
        y: Math.sin(angle) * radius
    };
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but perhaps this is the downvote for typo shouldn't be answered but commented.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Well, its a wierd logic on their side, but at lest i is some explanation.

Comment: @Archer Somtimes i'll just forgetting how hard it was to learn this thing at the begining.

Comment: Ok thank you, such a stupid mistake, i really should,ve noticed it by myself, despite being new.
 I'll accept as soon as system will allow me to do so.